# Error in databinding lightning:datatable selectedRows

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a datatable that displays a list of accounts. Based on some criteria, some of these accounts should be selected at the time that the datatable is rendered.

My Datatable looks like this

```
<!--This div will contain the result of person account search-->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showPersonResults}">
    <div aura:id="personsResult" class="slds-m-top_large dataTable-minHeight">
        <lightning:datatable aura:id="personTable"
                             data="{! v.persondata }"
                             columns="{! v.personcolumns }"
                             keyField="Id"
                             onrowaction="{! c.onRowActionFunction }"
                             onrowselection="{! c.onRowSelectionFunction}"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="{! empty(v.conventionId) }"
                             selectedRows="{! v.persondataSelected }"
                             class="dataTable-minHeight"
        />
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

My Databinding code looks like this

```
searchScreenService.findPersons(maxResults,conventionId,accPhone,accFirstName,accLastName,accEmail,accPostalCode).then(
    $A.getCallback(function(result) {
        if (result && result.searchResult.length > 0) {
            component.set('v.canCreateNewPersonAccount', true);
            component.set('v.showPersonResults', true);
            component.set('v.persondata', result.searchResult);
            component.set('v.persondataSelected', result.selectedRows);
        } else {
            component.set('v.canCreateNewPersonAccount', true);
            toastService.showSuccess($A.get("$Label.c.DC_No_results_found"));
        }
    }),
    $A.getCallback(function(error) {
        toastService.showError(error);
    })
);
```

The error I am getting is this one

```
"render threw an error in 'lightning:datatable' [Cannot read property '0' of undefined]"
```

If I put a timeout like this around the code that binds the selected rows to the table I get another error.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    component.set('v.persondataSelected', result.selectedRows);
}, 3000);
```

And the error:

```
The "selectedRows" passed into "lightning:datatable"
        must be an Array with the keys of the selected rows. We receive instead [object Object]
```

Any idea what I should do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found. It was caused by the `<aura:if></aura:if>` structure I put around the datatable. Following snippet works.

```
<div class="{!v.showPersonResults? '': 'slds-hide'}">
    <div aura:id="personsResult" class="slds-m-top_large dataTable-minHeight">
        <lightning:datatable aura:id="personTable"
                             data="{! v.persondata }"
                             columns="{! v.personcolumns }"
                             keyField="Id"
                             onrowaction="{! c.onRowActionFunction }"
                             onrowselection="{! c.onRowSelectionFunction}"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="{! empty(v.conventionId) }"
                             selectedRows="{! v.persondataSelected }"
                             class="dataTable-minHeight"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example#lightningComponentDemo:exampleDatatableRowSelection) here for handling preselection?

It looks like it expects an array of the keys the same as the `keyField` found on your `lightning:datatable`. So something like:

```
let selectedKeysArr = result.selectedRows
  .map((row) => {
    return row.Id
  });
component.set("v.persondataSelected", selectedKeysArr);
```

Comment: It is an array of ids [“123”,”234”,”345”] so your proposal should not make a difference

Comment: However, the error is very apparent, [object Object] is typically `var = {}` rather than `var = []`. If you `console.log(result.selectedRows)` does it actually output your of ids?

Comment: yes this is copy paste of the console.log (2) `["0014E00000qKbXmQAK", "0014E00000qKbXwQAK"]`